# CMD bat Why does %%a lose its value after the first loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Why does this bat file forget %%a after :theFound?  I am trying to understand how For /f works, but %%a is forgotten after the :theFound

Thanks for looking.

```
FOR /F %%a in (c:\temp\computers.txt) do (
echo %%a
set comPort=0
:comLoop
set /a comPort=%comPort%+1
reg query \\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Pergamon\AKT\Dienst\XFS\PASION_CM24_COM%comPort% 
if errorlevel 0 goto theFound
if %comPort% LSS 10 goto comLoop
echo No CRU found >>c:\temp\output1.txt
:theFound
reg query \\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOSA/XFS_ROOT\SERVICE_PROVIDERS\PASION_CM24_COM%comPort%\Firmware>>c:\temp\output1.txt
)
```

Comment: don't use `goto` or labels inside a `for` loop. They break the loop (so of course all loop-variables are lost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jumping inside a loop doesn't work, it breaks the loop. Instead you can call a subroutine (with `%%a` as parameter - in the subroutine it is referenced as `%1` = "first parameter"). Inside the subroutine you can jump as much as you want:

```
FOR /F %%a in (c:\temp\computers.txt) do call :doit %%a
goto :eof

:doit
set comPort=0
:comLoop
set /a comPort=%comPort%+1
reg query \\%1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Pergamon\AKT\Dienst\XFS\PASION_CM24_COM%comPort% 
if errorlevel 0 goto theFound
if %comPort% LSS 10 goto comLoop
echo No CRU found >>c:\temp\output1.txt
:theFound
reg query \\%1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOSA/XFS_ROOT\SERVICE_PROVIDERS\PASION_CM24_COM%comPort%\Firmware>>c:\temp\output1.txt
goto :eof
```

(Bonus: you don't need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082))